# Start to writing a bootloader for stm32l0 in IAR

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, bootloader, iar

What are the appropriate steps to write add a custom bootloader for stm32l0 in IAR? The following questions are not clear:

- Do I make a new IAR Project?

  - If yes, do I write the bootloader like a normal project and just change my original .icf file so there is a small ROM and an small RAM region for the bootloader?
  - if no, what things do I have to configure in the IAR proejct apart from icf file and code?
- what other things do I need to think of?

I'm having trouble starting into this.

So the icf would be for the main project:

```
__region_ROM_start__ = 0x08000000;
__region_ROM_end__ = 0x08008FFF;
```

So the icf would be for the bootloader project:

```
__region_Bootloader_ROM_start__ = 0x08009000;
__region_Bootloader_ROM_end__ = 0x08009FFF;
```

and the same thing for about `0xFF` of RAM?

Comment: A bootloader is just like any other project, with the exception that you have to carefully consider where it is allocated in flash, and what part of the flash it is supposed to program.

Comment: Useful link for people that land here : https://www.iar.com/support/tech-notes/general/creating-a-bootloader-for-cortex-m/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to restrict the RAM - you can use all of it because when you switch to the application a new run-time environment will be established and the RAM  will be reused.

The flash you reserve for the bootloader must be a whole number of flash pages starting from the reset address The STM32L0 has very small flash pages so there should be minimal waste, but you don't want to have to change it if your bootloader grows, because then you will have to rebuild your application code for the new start address and old application images will no longer be loadable.  So consider giving yourself a little headroom.

The bootloader can be built just like any other STM32L0xx project; the application code ROM configuration must start from an address above the bootloader.  So for example say you have a 1Kbyte bootloader:

```
Boot ROM Start:    0x0800 0000
Boot ROM End:      0x0800 03FF
Application Start: 0x0800 0400
Application End:   Part size dependent.
```

The bootloader itself must have a means of determining that an update is available, if an update *is* available it must then read the application data and write it to the application flash memory, it must then disable any interrupts that may have been enabled, it may also be necessary to deinitialise any peripherals used (if they remain active when the switch to the application is made it may cause problems), then the switch to the application code is made.

It is possible if the bootloader and application both run from the same clock configuration to minimise the configuration in the application and rely on the bootloader.  This is a small space saving, but less flexible.  If for example you make the bootloader run using the internal RC oscillator it will be portable across multiple hardware designs that may have differing application speed and clocking requirements and different external oscillator frequencies

The switch to the application is pretty simple on Cortex-M, it simply requires the vector table to be switched to the application's vector table, then the program-counter to be loaded - the latter requires a little assembly code.  The following is for Cortex-M3, it may need some adaptation for M0+ but possibly not:

Given the following in-line assembly function:

```
__asm void boot_jump( uint32_t address )
{
   LDR SP, [R0]       ;Load new stack pointer address
   LDR PC, [R0, #4]   ;Load new program counter address
}
```

The bootloader switched to the application image thus:

```
// Switch off core clock before switching vector table
SysTick->CTRL = 0 ;

// Switch off any other enabled interrupts too
...

// Switch vector table
SCB->VTOR = APPLICATION_START_ADDR ;

//Jump to start address
boot_jump( APPLICATION_START_ADDR ) ;
```

Where APPLICATION_START_ADDR is the base address of the application area; this address is the start of the application's vector table, which starts with the initial stack pointer and reset vector, the `boot_jump()` function loads these into the SP and PC registers to start the application as if it had been started at reset.  The application's reset vector contains the application's execution start address.

Your needs may vary, but in my experience a serial bootloader (using UART) using XMODEM and decoding an image in Intel Hex format takes about 4Kb of Flash.  On an STM32L0 you may want to use something simpler - 1Kb is probably feasible if you simply stream raw binary the data and use hardware flow control (you need to control data flow because erasing and programming the flash takes time and also stops the CPU from running because you cannot on STM32 write flash memory while simultaneously fetching instructions from it).

See also: [How to jump between programs in Stellaris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393715/how-to-jump-between-programs-in-stellaris/14406706#14406706)