# Jump to another application

Tags: embedded, stm32, bootloader

I want to write a bootloader for my stm32l4 mcu which (after pressing a button) jumps to another part of flash and run the app on that part.
for application part I write a simple blinky and generate its BIN file and copy this bin file to address 0x0800 8000 of flash memory.

Now I do not know how can I jump to this address and run this blinky app.

would anyone help me?

best!

Comment: I'd mark this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393715/how-to-jump-between-programs-in-stellaris/14406706 except that is for Stellaris - the answer however applies to any Cortex-M3 or M4.

Comment: Why exactly can't you use a function? Are you flashing the code in multiple steps or something? Running code from data flash?

Answer (score 0):

At least two alternatives spring to mind:

1. Use a function pointer:

   ```
       /* ... */
       void (*app)(void) = (void (*)(void))0x08008000;
       app();
   ```
2. Declare an external function and resolve it with your linker script:

   ```
       /* ... */
       void app(void);
       app();
   ```

   How to define the address in the linker script depends on your linker.

Comment: Would you explain more?

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: There are other issues to consider, such as disabling interrupts and possible re-initialisation of some hardware devices.  Also that code will still be using the bootloader rather than the application stack and vector table.  `0x08008000` is  the start of the application vector table, not the application entry point.  The vector table start has the stack-pointer and reset-vector address in that order.  You need to load these to SP and PC to effect a valid application switch.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could also rewrite the Interrupt Vector Table. I dont know exactly how the stm32l4 works, but have a look at the start up code. At some point it loads the program counter with a predefined value. You could rewrite this value and reset the MCU.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.